# Knight's Travails and Binary Search Tree

Tags: ruby, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree, graph-algorithm

Here is some context if you're unfamiliar with Knight's Travails.

> Your task is to build a function knight_moves that shows the simplest possible way to get from one square to another by outputting all squares the knight will stop on along the way.

I know where to find complete solutions to this exercise, but I'm trying to mostly work through it on my own.

Where I'm stuck is how to set up a binary tree, or, specifically, what is the relationship between all the next possible moves a knight can make from its current location?

As I understand a BST, the defining property is that a tree(and any of its subtrees and leaves) store keys that are larger to the root node to the right, and smaller keys to the left of the root node.

How do I represent the value of the knight's current location and its possible(valid) moves?

It would be more valuable if the answer provided is a more of a guiding principle (philosophy?) when thinking about BST keys/values and defining parent-child relationships.

Thank you.

Comment: I just signed up and this is my first question; please excuse any conventions I may have violated.

Comment: Since you haven't posted so much as pseudo-code, there's a limited amount of help we can give.

Comment: I didn't see giving pseudo-code as necessary because I was really just looking for a perspective on defining keys/values and parent-child relationships of BSTs in general and as it pertains to Knight's Travails.

Your help was sufficient. Thank you.

I am, however, still curious about the aforementioned perspective on BSTs _in general._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a BST problem.  Attack this as a graph search problem with backtracking.  Start by learning and understanding [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), treating the squares of the board as nodes in a graph.  For instance, a1 connects to b3 and c2; all moves have a cost of 1 (which simplifies the algorithm a little).

You'll need to build your graph either before you start, connecting all possible moves; or on the fly, generating all possibilities from the current square.  Most students find that doing it on the fly is easier for them.

Also, changing from algebraic chess notation to (row, col) notation helps.  If the knight is currently at (row, col), then the legal next moves are

```
(row+-2, col +-1) and
(row+-1, col +-2)
```

... where x and y are both in the range 0-7 (throw out moves that take the knight past the board's edge).

Maintain a global list of squares you've already visited, and another of squares you need to visit (one move from those you've visited).  You'll also need an array of least cost (number of moves) to get to each square.  Initialize that to 100, and let the algorithm reduce it as it walks through the search.

Is that enough to get you moving?

Comment: Thank you. I've come across this idea. The exercise prompt says:  _Treat all possible moves the knight could make as children in a tree._

My initial approach (before seeking out direction) was to treat each possible move as a node INSTEAD of treating each square as a node. Each move(node) was considered point_b, and each node had an associated point_a that represents its origin(preceding location).

I was able to get it to work, but certain combinations of coordinates (origin,destination) result in a stack overflow, while other combinations successfully generate the path from a to b.

Comment: What I did was generate a list of possible_moves(node) based on a location. I then check each node to see if it contains the destination point. If it doesn't, it I'll take the coordinates from the first node of possible_moves and generate a new set of possible_moves to scan for the destination. I set it up as a breadth first search, so it only populates a new generation after the current generation has been checked.

Comment: Then I suspect that your overflow problem was one of not pruning the search.  Generate all "next" mvoes ... but if you've already visited a square, or already have on the "to-do" list, then don't add it to the "to-do" list again.  That's one important point of Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: Yes, I had come across this as well, but I wasn't sure where in my code I would implement it. I figured it out.

Comment: Excellent!  Please remember to accept your favourite answer -- even if you have to write one yourself.

Comment: Great.  Please retire the question properly by accepting your favorite answer -- even if you have to write it yourself.

Comment: Hey, I'm super late but how do you actually build this graph in JavaScript?

Comment: That's a new technical issue in a different language.  Post as a separate question.  Show your work so far and describe where you're stuck.